analytical solution of an equation
I am trying to find analytic solutions of the following equation for $\omega>0$
$$ 0 = -\frac{a}{b}RJ(R+b^2) + (a^2+b^2)\bigg[ MaJ+\frac{R}{a}(R+b^2)\bigg] \cos(al)\sinh(bl) + (a^2+b^2)\bigg[ MbJ+\frac{R}{b}(R-a^2)\bigg]\sin(al) \cosh(bl)+ \bigg[ RJ(a^2+b^2)+\frac{b}{a}RJ(R-a^2)-M(a^2 +b^2)^2)\bigg]\sin(al)\sinh(bl)- J\bigg[ \frac{a}{b}(R-a^2)+\frac{b}{a}(R+b^2)\bigg]\cos(al)\cosh(bl)
$$
with
$$
 a = \sqrt{\frac{\rho}{2KG} \omega^2 +\sqrt{ \left(\frac{\rho}{2KG} \omega^2 \right)^2 + \frac{\rho A}{EI}\omega^2}}  \\ b = \sqrt{-\frac{\rho}{2KG} \omega^2 +\sqrt{ \left(\frac{\rho}{2KG} \omega^2 \right)^2 + \frac{\rho A}{EI}\omega^2}}
$$
and
$$
R= \frac{\rho \omega^2}{KG}
$$
$\omega$ is the variable and everything else is a real number
Can someone help me solve this or recommend a software to solve it? I tried MATLAB already but it only solved it numerically. And I need a closed form for the first two solutions. Thank you.

Are you sure there are no simplifications to the equation?

have you tried https://www.wolframalpha.com/ ?

Wolframalpha is not working its stopping the calculations midway, do you think Mathematica could work?@max

@ТymaGaidash Iam not sure  but I tried my best to simplify it
